# change content of a column by using nested if else statement - R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am working on the diamonds dataset:

```
> dput(head(diamonds_small, 100))
structure(list(carat = c(0.23, 0.21, 0.23, 0.29, 0.31, 0.24, 
0.24, 0.26, 0.22, 0.23, 0.3, 0.23, 0.22, 0.31, 0.2, 0.32, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.23, 0.23, 0.31, 0.31, 0.23, 0.24, 0.3, 
0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.31, 0.26, 
0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.26, 0.26, 0.32, 0.29, 0.32, 0.32, 0.25, 0.29, 
0.24, 0.23, 0.32, 0.22, 0.22, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.35, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.42, 0.28, 0.32, 0.31, 0.31, 0.24, 0.24, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 
0.38, 0.26, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.32, 0.7, 0.86, 0.7, 0.71, 
0.78, 0.7, 0.7, 0.96, 0.73, 0.8), cut = structure(c(5L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("Fair", "Good", "Very Good", "Premium", "Ideal"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), color = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 
6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 5L), .Label = c("D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), clarity = structure(c(2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("I1", 
"SI2", "SI1", "VS2", "VS1", "VVS2", "VVS1", "IF"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), depth = c(61.5, 59.8, 56.9, 62.4, 63.3, 62.8, 62.3, 
61.9, 65.1, 59.4, 64, 62.8, 60.4, 62.2, 60.2, 60.9, 62, 63.4, 
63.8, 62.7, 63.3, 63.8, 61, 59.4, 58.1, 60.4, 62.5, 62.2, 60.5, 
60.9, 60, 59.8, 60.7, 59.5, 61.9, 58.2, 64.1, 64, 60.8, 61.8, 
61.2, 61.1, 65.2, 58.4, 63.1, 62.4, 61.8, 63.8, 63.3, 60.7, 60.9, 
61.9, 60.9, 61.6, 59.3, 61, 59.3, 62.6, 63, 63.2, 60.9, 62.6, 
62.5, 62.1, 61.5, 61.4, 62, 63.3, 61.8, 60.7, 61.5, 63.1, 62.9, 
62.5, 63.7, 59.2, 59.9, 62.4, 62.8, 62.6, 63.4, 62.1, 62.9, 61.6, 
57.9, 62.3, 61.2, 60.8, 60.7, 62.9, 62.5, 55.1, 61.6, 62.4, 63.8, 
57.5, 59.4, 66.3, 61.6, 61.5), table = c(55, 61, 65, 58, 58, 
57, 57, 55, 61, 61, 55, 56, 61, 54, 62, 58, 54, 54, 56, 59, 56, 
55, 57, 62, 62, 58, 57, 57, 61, 57, 57, 57, 59, 58, 58, 59, 59, 
54, 59, 55, 56, 56, 56, 63, 56, 58, 55, 56, 60, 60, 61, 54, 55, 
58, 62, 59, 61, 57, 57, 55, 57, 59, 57, 56, 59, 56, 55.3, 57, 
58, 58, 60, 56, 59, 57, 57, 60, 58, 54, 60, 59, 59, 60, 58, 56, 
60, 59, 58, 59, 58, 58, 57, 69, 56, 57, 56, 58, 62, 62, 59, 58
), price = c(326L, 326L, 327L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 336L, 337L, 
337L, 338L, 339L, 340L, 342L, 344L, 345L, 345L, 348L, 351L, 351L, 
351L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 353L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 357L, 357L, 357L, 
402L, 402L, 402L, 402L, 402L, 402L, 402L, 402L, 403L, 403L, 403L, 
403L, 403L, 403L, 403L, 403L, 403L, 403L, 404L, 404L, 404L, 404L, 
404L, 404L, 404L, 405L, 405L, 405L, 405L, 405L, 552L, 552L, 552L, 
552L, 552L, 553L, 553L, 553L, 553L, 553L, 553L, 554L, 554L, 554L, 
554L, 554L, 554L, 554L, 554L, 554L, 554L, 554L, 554L, 554L, 554L, 
554L, 554L, 554L, 554L, 554L, 2757L, 2757L, 2757L, 2759L, 2759L, 
2759L, 2759L, 2759L, 2760L, 2760L), x = c(3.95, 3.89, 4.05, 4.2, 
4.34, 3.94, 3.95, 4.07, 3.87, 4, 4.25, 3.93, 3.88, 4.35, 3.79, 
4.38, 4.31, 4.23, 4.23, 4.21, 4.26, 3.85, 3.94, 4.39, 4.44, 3.97, 
3.97, 4.28, 3.96, 3.96, 4, 4.04, 3.97, 4.01, 3.92, 4.06, 3.83, 
4.29, 4.13, 4.49, 4.49, 4.49, 3.99, 4.19, 4.34, 4.24, 4.35, 4.36, 
4, 4.33, 4.02, 3.93, 4.45, 3.93, 3.91, 4.3, 4.43, 4.25, 4.28, 
4.25, 4.54, 4.23, 4.29, 4.3, 4.78, 4.19, 4.39, 4.33, 4.35, 4.01, 
3.97, 4.29, 4.28, 4.29, 4.28, 4.19, 4.15, 4.08, 4.01, 4.06, 4, 
4.03, 4.02, 4.65, 4.22, 3.95, 4.01, 4.02, 4.07, 4.35, 5.7, 6.45, 
5.7, 5.68, 5.81, 5.85, 5.71, 6.27, 5.77, 5.97), y = c(3.98, 3.84, 
4.07, 4.23, 4.35, 3.96, 3.98, 4.11, 3.78, 4.05, 4.28, 3.9, 3.84, 
4.37, 3.75, 4.42, 4.34, 4.29, 4.26, 4.27, 4.3, 3.92, 3.96, 4.43, 
4.47, 4.01, 3.94, 4.3, 3.97, 3.99, 4.03, 4.06, 4.01, 4.06, 3.96, 
4.08, 3.85, 4.31, 4.16, 4.51, 4.5, 4.55, 4.02, 4.24, 4.37, 4.26, 
4.42, 4.38, 4.03, 4.37, 4.03, 3.95, 4.48, 3.89, 3.88, 4.33, 4.38, 
4.28, 4.32, 4.29, 4.59, 4.27, 4.32, 4.33, 4.84, 4.22, 4.42, 4.3, 
4.32, 4.03, 4, 4.27, 4.24, 4.25, 4.26, 4.22, 4.23, 4.13, 4.05, 
4.09, 4.04, 4.12, 4.06, 4.67, 4.25, 3.92, 3.96, 4, 4.04, 4.33, 
5.72, 6.33, 5.67, 5.73, 5.85, 5.9, 5.76, 5.95, 5.78, 5.93), z = c(2.43, 
2.31, 2.31, 2.63, 2.75, 2.48, 2.47, 2.53, 2.49, 2.39, 2.73, 2.46, 
2.33, 2.71, 2.27, 2.68, 2.68, 2.7, 2.71, 2.66, 2.71, 2.48, 2.41, 
2.62, 2.59, 2.41, 2.47, 2.67, 2.4, 2.42, 2.41, 2.42, 2.42, 2.4, 
2.44, 2.37, 2.46, 2.75, 2.52, 2.78, 2.75, 2.76, 2.61, 2.46, 2.75, 
2.65, 2.71, 2.79, 2.54, 2.64, 2.45, 2.44, 2.72, 2.41, 2.31, 2.63, 
2.61, 2.67, 2.71, 2.7, 2.78, 2.66, 2.69, 2.68, 2.96, 2.58, 2.73, 
2.73, 2.68, 2.44, 2.45, 2.7, 2.68, 2.67, 2.72, 2.49, 2.51, 2.56, 
2.53, 2.55, 2.55, 2.53, 2.54, 2.87, 2.45, 2.45, 2.44, 2.44, 2.46, 
2.73, 3.57, 3.52, 3.5, 3.56, 3.72, 3.38, 3.4, 4.07, 3.56, 3.66
)), .Names = c("carat", "cut", "color", "clarity", "depth", "table", 
"price", "x", "y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to change the column `cut` such that all observations that contain 'ideal' or 'premium' will have 'above average', all observations with 'good' and 'fair' will have 'below average. I have tried two codes, but none of them work. Here they are:

```
cut_new <- 
  ifelse(diamonds_small$cut == "Ideal", "Above average", 
      ifelse(diamonds_small$cut == "Premium", "Above average", 
          ifelse(diamonds_small$cut == "Very Good", "Very Good",
              ifelse(diamonds_small$cut == "Good", "Below average", 
                  ifelse(diamonds_small$cut == "Fair", "Below average")))))


if ( diamonds_small$cut = "Ideal") {
  diamonds_small$cut == "Above average"
} else if ( diamonds_small$cut == "Premium") {
  diamonds_small$cut == "Above average"
} else if ( diamonds_small$cut == "Good") {
  diamonds_small$cut == "Below average"
} else if ( diamonds_small$cut == "Fair") {
  diamonds_small$cut == "Below average"  
} else
  diamonds_small$cut == "other"
```

Disclaimer: **I NEED TO USE IFELSE**

Any tips, comments will be greatly appriciated

Comment: If you need to use ifelse, I'd go for `ifelse(df$cut %in% c("Ideal", "Premium"), "Above Average", ifelse(df$cut %in% c("Good", "Fair"), "Below Average", "other"))`

Answer (score 2):

We can change the column `cut` to `character` and then the `ifelse` would work

```
diamonds_small$cut <- as.character(diamonds_small$cut)
```

In the last line of `ifelse`, the 'no' is missing

```
ifelse(diamonds_small$cut == "Ideal", "Above average", 
   ifelse(diamonds_small$cut == "Premium", "Above average", 
       ifelse(diamonds_small$cut == "Very Good", "Very Good",
           ifelse(diamonds_small$cut == "Good", "Below average", 
               ifelse(diamonds_small$cut == "Fair", "Below average", NA)))))
```

The usage of `ifelse` is

> ifelse(test, yes, no)

---

Or otherwise use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
diamonds_small %>% 
    mutate(cut_new = case_when(cut  %in% c("Ideal", "Premium") ~ "Above average", 
         cut == "Very Good" ~ "Very Good", 
         cut %in% c("Good", "Fair") ~ "Below average" ))
# A tibble: 100 x 11
#   carat       cut color clarity depth table price     x     y     z       cut_new
#   <dbl>     <ord> <ord>   <ord> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <chr>
# 1  0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43 Above average
# 2  0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31 Above average
# 3  0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31 Below average
# 4  0.29   Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334  4.20  4.23  2.63 Above average
# 5  0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75 Below average
# 6  0.24 Very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48     Very Good
# 7  0.24 Very Good     I    VVS1  62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47     Very Good
# 8  0.26 Very Good     H     SI1  61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53     Very Good
# 9  0.22      Fair     E     VS2  65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49 Below average
#10  0.23 Very Good     H     VS1  59.4    61   338  4.00  4.05  2.39     Very Good
# ... with 90 more rows
```

---

Whenever we have multiple replacements, the ideal approach would be to have a `key/value` dataset and then merge with the original dataset

```
keydat <- data.frame(cut = c("Ideal", "Premium", "Very Good", "Good", "Fair"),
 val = c("Above average", "Above average", "Very Good", "Below average", 
        "Below average"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
left_join(diamonds_small, keydat)
# A tibble: 100 x 11
#   carat       cut color clarity depth table price     x     y     z           val
#   <dbl>     <chr> <ord>   <ord> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <chr>
# 1  0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43 Above average
# 2  0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31 Above average
# 3  0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31 Below average
# 4  0.29   Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334  4.20  4.23  2.63 Above average
# 5  0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75 Below average
# 6  0.24 Very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48     Very Good
# 7  0.24 Very Good     I    VVS1  62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47     Very Good
# 8  0.26 Very Good     H     SI1  61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53     Very Good
# 9  0.22      Fair     E     VS2  65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49 Below average
#10  0.23 Very Good     H     VS1  59.4    61   338  4.00  4.05  2.39     Very Good
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Note that we avoided the multiple `ifelse/case_when` etc. in a single step of `left_join`.  Also, there is a limit for the number of `ifelse` statements (could be 56 or so) and would be slower with nested `ifelse`

Comment: I still get an error for both code. In the first one: `Error in ifelse(diamonds_small$cut == "Fair", "Below average") : 
  argument "no" is missing, with no default` and in the second : `In if (diamonds_small$cut == "Ideal") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`. I need to use `ifelse`

Comment: @Danka You need `ifelse(diamonds_small$cut == "Fair", "Below average", NA)))))`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this recoding using the `dplyr`'s `mutate()` and  `recode()` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
diamonds_small %>% mutate(cutNew = recode(cut, Ideal = "Above average",
                                          Premium = "Above average",
                                          Good = "Below average",
                                          Fair = "Below average"))

# # A tibble: 100 x 11
#   carat       cut color clarity depth table price     x     y     z        cutNew
#   <dbl>     <ord> <ord>   <ord> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <ord>
# 1  0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43 Above average
# 2  0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31 Above average
# 3  0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31 Below average
# 4  0.29   Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334  4.20  4.23  2.63 Above average
# 5  0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75 Below average
# 6  0.24 Very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48     Very Good
# 7  0.24 Very Good     I    VVS1  62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47     Very Good
# 8  0.26 Very Good     H     SI1  61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53     Very Good
# 9  0.22      Fair     E     VS2  65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49 Below average
# 10  0.23 Very Good     H     VS1  59.4    61   338  4.00  4.05  2.39     Very Good
# # ... with 90 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd first make sure that the columns are `characters` instead of coded as `factors`. Then I'd proceed with indexing to replace the values.

```
diamonds_small$cut <- as.character(diamonds_small$cut)

inds  <- diamonds_small$cut %in% c("Ideal", "Premium")
inds2 <- diamonds_small$cut %in% c("Fair", "Good")
inds3 <- diamonds_small$cut == "Very Good"    

diamonds_small$cut[inds]  <- "Above Average"
diamonds_small$cut[inds2] <- "Below Average"
diamonds_small$cut[ (inds + inds 2 > 0) ] <- "other"
diamonds_small$cut[inds3] <- "Very Good"
```

I'm sure there are many ways to achieve this. The advantage of this approach is that it does not require additional packages. Additionally, this type of logic is very versatile and applies to many situations in `R`

Comment: This would be my personal favorite, but you're missing the `"Very Good"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `mapvalues` from `plyr`:

```
require(plyr)
data$cut <- mapvalues(data$cut,c("Ideal","Premium","Good","Fair"),c(rep("above average",2),rep("below average",2)))
```